# How to animate a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiprogressbar

I have a UITableViewCell. I'm trying to animate a progress bar when the cell comes into view. I have tried the following but it does nothing.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellId = @"TableViewCellResult";

    TableViewCellResults *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TableViewCellResults alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }

    // Add progress bar here

    // THIS DOES NOTHING
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.f animations:^{
        progressBar.value = 55.f;
    }];
```

How do I animate the UIProgressBar? The UIProgressBar does not accept 'animateWithDuration'.

I have working sample of animating the UIProgressBar in UIView (not a cell)
that uses the same syntax.

Comment: Is the progress bar contained within the cell?

Comment: You've left out the important code. Show your complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Try putting animation code in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` or `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`

Comment: Yes.. progress bar in cell.

Comment: Can't paste the full cellForRowAt - too many chars

Comment: I have tried adding this: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.f animations:^{
             self.progressBar.value = 55.f;
         }];
        
}

Comment: But does not animate.. does get fired

Comment: Is UIView correct for willDisplayCell?  tableView does not have animateWithDuration

Answer (score 0):

Try perform animations using **UIView.commmitAnimations()** eg:

```
 UIView.beginAnimations(“rotation”, context: nil)

    UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.8)

    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity

    cell.alpha = 1

    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: CGFloat(0), height: CGFloat(0))

    UIView.commitAnimations()
```

also try to perform the operation inside **willDisplayCell:** Method.

Refer this http://www.thinkandbuild.it/animating-uitableview-cells/ solution to perform animations inside tableview cell